# javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013

Tags: java, wildfly

Переношу проект со старого сервера (debian 7, wildfly 8.2.0) на новый (debian 9, wildfly 16). 
Сервер запускается, но при http запросе появляется ошибка:

```
2019-04-22 07:59:05,891 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Track//GetTrackAsCBOR: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate GetTrackAsCBOR
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:300)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.forceInit(ManagedServlet.java:210)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain.forceInit(ServletChain.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentRegistry$ComponentManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ComponentRegistry.java:149)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$6.createInstance(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1215)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:298)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ConstructorComponentFactory.create(ConstructorComponentFactory.java:27)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:26)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ConstructorComponentFactory.create(ConstructorComponentFactory.java:24)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /settings.ini (Нет такого файла или каталога)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at Utils.IniSettings.<init>(IniSettings.java:30)
    at GetTrackAsCBOR.<init>(GetTrackAsCBOR.java:22)
    ... 62 more
```

Все пакеты, пути и модули в системе есть. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

У вас самая первая причина, по которой ошибка и создалась это

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /settings.ini (Нет такого файла или каталога)
```

Добавьте его в вашу директорию

Comment: Уже пытался это сделать, с такими же путями как и на старом сервере - безуспешно.

Comment: @sintez, Видимо у вас корневая директория не та. У вас четко указана причина. 
 Если вы можете изменить код или у вас есть логгер,куда вы можете 
 подкинуть файл, который укажет вам корневую директорию, то было бы неплохо. А так, может у вас корнем является папка, где java хранится, либо откуда запускается программа, либо где она расположена. Много вариантов.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @sintez, так в чём проблема то оказалась? )

Comment: пока не знаю, пытаюсь найти, где указан путь к этому файлу

Comment: На старом сервере попробуйте 
`find . -name settings.ini` Если файлов не очень много то можно так, в противном случае, начинайте с директории, где запускается / лежит программа

Comment: уже пробовал. Даже grep -ir settings.ini по всей системе делал, пока не понятно.

Comment: вы можете в дебагере открыть программу и запустить ее на старом сервере? И посмотреть абсолютный путь файла в момент запуска? или перекомпилировать программу с добавлением такой строчки?

Comment: Пока что решил проблему, положив этот файлик в корень системы. Буду писать разработчику.